# Parametrising over "higher-kinded" types in Idris

Tags: monads, idris

I just started playing around with Idris, and tried shoe-horning some Haskell machines into it:

```
namespace works
  data Auto a b = AutoC (a -> (b, Auto a b))

  const_auto : b -> Auto a b
  const_auto b = AutoC (\_ => (b, const_auto b))
```

However, I'd like now to generalize `Auto a b` to `AutoM m a b` to take an extra parameter so it can generate its output monadically, with `m` being the monad. My intuition would have been that `m` would have type `Type -> Type`, but then the type-checker complains that that doesn't match `(Type, Type) -> Type`. So I tried leaving it a little more polymorphic:

```
namespace doesntwork

  data AutoM : {x : Type } -> (m : x -> Type) -> (a : Type) -> (b : Type) -> Type where
     AutoMC : (a -> m (b, AutoM m a b)) -> AutoM m a b

  data Identity a = IdentityC a

  Auto : Type -> Type -> Type
  Auto = AutoM Identity
```

This at least type-checks. But when I try:

```
  const_auto : Monad m => {m : x -> Type } -> {a : Type} -> b -> AutoM m a b
  const_auto b = AutoMC (\_ => return (b, const_auto b))
```

That, however, is no good:

```
When elaborating right hand side of Stream.doesntwork.const_auto:
When elaborating an application of function Prelude.Monad.return:
        Can't unify
                (A, B) (Type of (a, b))
        with
                (b, AutoM m4 a b) (Expected type)
```

And I can't make much sense of the type error. Why in the world would the type of `(a, b)` be mentioned, when `a` isn't used anywhere in the definition of `const_auto`? I have the feeling the definition of `AutoM` itself is already at fault, but I don't really know why or how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right when your intuition told you that `m` being a monad, it should have type `Type -> Type`. The problem here is that [`(,)` is overloaded](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#tuples-and-dependent-pairs) to mean both the `Pair` type constructor and the `mkPair` data constructor and Idris' elaborator makes the wrong choice.

By picking explicitly `Pair`, you fix the definition:

```
data AutoM : (m : Type -> Type) -> (a : Type) -> (b : Type) -> Type where
   AutoMC : (a -> m (Pair b (AutoM m a b))) -> AutoM m a b
```

Now, if you just do that you'll get another cryptic message:

```
Auto.idr:18:14:
When elaborating right hand side of Main.doesntwork.const_auto:
Can't resolve type class Monad m3
Metavariables: Main.doesntwork.const_auto
```

The problem here is the fact that you introduce an implicit `m` in the type annotation of `const_auto` which is different from the one *already introduced* by the constraint `Monad m =>` and so Idris cannot find a `Monad` instance for this new `m`. The solution is to not introduce it at all (the constraint mentioning an `m` being enough for it to be in scope) like so:

```
const_auto : Monad m => {a : Type} -> b -> AutoM m a b
```